# What's the difference between using "of" and using "with" when showing a cause?

Tags: word-usage, differences, prepositions, predicate-frames

What is the sense of a sentence when *of* and *with* are variously used to show the cause of something?

1. He died **of** cancer.
2. He was shivering **with** cold.

Why isn’t it like this, or can it be? If it can be, do they mean the same thing as the prior pair, or do they mean something else again?

3. He died **with** cancer.
4. He was shivering **of** cold.

Comment: Have you looked both words up in a dictionary?

Comment: I only used it for showing different as a preposition not as a word but by mistake didn't placed it before the latter

Comment: @PeterJennings I looked up both words many times but I couldn't understand this difference

Comment: The difference is that these are two different words. There is no rule any native speaker learns. And so there is no rule that you can learn. You just have to learn the usage of each word by heart, just like everyone else. That is all.

Comment: @RegDwigнt but can you explain to me what is the mean

Comment: I am sure there is *some* kind of rule that is being employed here (and ideally more than just *because*), even if only in this specific case, but it's not one that (as far as I'm aware) has ever been put into words. Any way I look at it, I can't come up with a way of expressing why *of* is used in the one sentence and *with* in the other. At best it seems to be an *unconsciously understood* rule. However, despite not my inability to to provide an immediately helpful answer, this is an excellent question.

Comment: Just as an aside, you would usually say *he was shivering from the cold*.

Answer (score -1):

He died "of" Covid. - Covid was the actual cause of death.

He died  "with" Covid - he died of causes unrelated to COVID but was found to have been tested and had COVID at the time of his death.

"Of" was used by the media and government to justify lockdowns and restrictions when they had no way of determining if COVID actually killed people. It suited their purpose to strike fear in the hearts of the nation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your last paragraph is off topic. The first is correct, and the second is nearly correct - If somebody died *with* Covid it is not stated whether it was the cause of death - it may or may not be.